# Using apache poi in selenium for reading Excel file but when trying to run code in java it is showing nullpointerException Error

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, nullpointerexception

When running this code it is showing nullpointerException error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at npackage.ReadindDataFromExcel.main(ReadindDataFromExcel.java:48)*

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com");

    //Excel File location
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("C://Datafirst.xls");

    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
    int noOfRows = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    System.out.println("No.of Records in the Excel Sheet:" + noOfRows);
    //int colcount=sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();

    for (int row = 0; row <= noOfRows; row++)
    {
        HSSFRow currentrow = sheet.getRow(row);
        String First_name = currentrow.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the "java" tag to your question, you're more likely to reach people if they know it's about a language they know. As a new user, please don't forget to visit [tour] and [ask] if you haven't already.

Comment: Have you tried to use debugger? Also it would be nice if you somehow marked line 48, which throws exception, in provided code.